# Translation of link not working

Tags: module, inline-translations

Follow the examples of magento, normal text translates correctly, but this links does not translate.

Csv

```
"Click <a href=""%s"" onclick=""this.target=\'_blank\'"">here</a> and register for free.","Clique <a href=""%s"" onclick=""this.target=\'_blank\'"">aqui</a> e cadastre-se grátis."
```

Samples that tested

```
Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here</a> and register for free.', $url);

Mage::helper('core')->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here</a> and register for free.', $url);

$this->__('Click <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">here</a> and register for free.', $url);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Magento: Single Quotes in Translation Files Void Translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605424/magento-single-quotes-in-translation-files-void-translation)

Should be in .csv file:

```
"Click <a href=""%s"" onclick=""this.target='_blank'"">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation.", "Click <a href=""%s"" onclick=""this.target='_blank'"">here to print</a> a copy of your order confirmation."
```

without the backslashes, otherwise the string won't get translated. As usual double-quotes in the .csv have to be escaped with another double-quotes.

Comment: check success.phtml and Mage_Checkout.csv, follows the pattern of them, then I believe that is not the (",')

Comment: removed the slashes as your example and it worked, thanks